# How to read formatted input in python?

Tags: python, input

I want to read from stdin five numbers entered as follows:

3, 4, 5, 1, 8

into seperate variables a,b,c,d & e.

How do I do this in python?

I tried this:

```
import string
a=input()
b=a.split(', ')
```

for two integers, but it does not work. I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\comb.py", line 3, in <module>
    b=a.split(', ')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How to do this? and suppose I have not a fixed but a variable number n integers. Then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input()`.

```
# Python 2.5.4
>>> a = raw_input()
3, 4, 5
>>> a
'3, 4, 5'
>>> b = a.split(', ')
>>> b
['3', '4', '5']
>>> [s.strip() for s in raw_input().split(",")] # one liner
3, 4, 5
['3', '4', '5']
```

The misleadingly names [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) function does not do what you'd expect it to. It actually evaluates the input from stdin as python code.

In your case it turns out that what you then have is a tuple of numbers in `a`, all parsed and ready for work, but generally you don't really want to use this curious side effect. Other inputs can cause any number of things to happen.

Incidentally, in Python 3 they fixed this, and now the [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) function does what you'd expect.

Two more things:

1. You don't need to `import string` to do simple string manipulations.
2. Like mjv [said](http://#1397838), to split a tuple or a list into several variables, you can 'unpack' it. This will not be feasible if you don't know how long the list will be, though.

Unpacking:

```
>>> l = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> a,b,c,d,e = l
>>> e
5
```

Comment: In Python 3.1 input() returns string.

Comment: Yes, but the poster is obviously using 2.X

Answer (score 3):

**Under Python 2.x only**  (*)

after a = input()

a is a tuple with the 5 values readily parsed!

A quick way to assign these 5 values is

```
a, b, c, d, e = a
```

(*) with Python version 3.0? or for sure 3.1, input() works more like the raw_input() method of 2.x, which makes it less confusing.  (thank you mshsayem to point this out!)

Comment: IN python 3.1 input function does not 'eval' user input. As in http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html: "...The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that..."

Answer (score 0):

If you print out a (the variable containing your input) you will find out, that a already contains a tuple. You do not have to split the contents.

> >>> a = input()
>     3, 4, 5, 1, 8
>     >>> print(a)
>     (3, 4, 5, 1, 8)
>     >>> type(a)
>     <type 'tuple'>
>     >>> a[0]
>     3
>     >>> len(a)
>     5

Answer (score -3):

```
in = eval(input())

a, b, c, d, e = in
```