# create a list from separated comma items in a file

Tags: python, nltk

Hi I have the following script, but this script is retriving items ranged in a file this way

```
ca1
ca2
ca3
```

and my new text file is ranged this way

ca1, ca2, ca3

So this is my script what shoud i modify to make it that way?

```
with open('fileids2.txt', 'r') as f:
genres=[line.strip() for line in f]  

freq = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
 (genre, m)
  for genre in brown.fileids()
  for m in brown.words(fileids=genre))

adj = ["new", "such", "own","good",]
freq.tabulate(conditions=genres, samples=adj)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read formatted input in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397827/how-to-read-formatted-input-in-python)

Comment: Does your new text file only have a single line with values separated by commas, or can it have several lines?

Comment: @Stuart Only a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data file is quite simple you can just `split` the line.

```
with open('fileids2.txt', 'r') as f:
    genres = [word.strip() for word in f.next().split(',')]
```

If there is a possibility of commas within a data item (e.g. something like `ca1, "ca, 2", ca3`) then you should use the `csv` module to parse it properly, as in @JoãoGFarias's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *csv* module.

```
from csv import reader
with open('fileids2.txt', 'r') as f:
     words= reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
     for word in words:
         print ','.join(word)
```

This will output the line on the file as it is written there:

```
ca1, ca2, ca3
```

The aforementioned code also works for multi-line files.

You can read more about the `csv` module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Hi, im getting this:  Attribute Error: ‘module’ object has no attribute ‘reader"

Comment: Probably just a configuration problem with the import.
I edited the code, try it now.

If you get the error again, make sure you have the *cvs* module. Type *import cvs* on your Python console. 
I'm pretty sure it comes with the standard library, but maybe you don't have it.

Comment: @JoãoGFarias it's `csv` not `cvs` and yes, it's part of the stdlib - I'm guessing the OP doesn't have a problem with `import csv`, but they're later doing `csv = something` and it's that `csv` object that is raises the `AttributeError` as it's no longer a reference to the module

Comment: Yeah @JonClements, you're right; typo.
The code was running ok in my machine, I don't understood was it is not working for Jose. Maybe his Python path is different some way. The standard library is automatic linked on the Python path when you install the language. Anyway, the code prints the result correctly :)

Comment: @JoãoGFarias i just test importing the csv modue and it works fine but if its from csv import reader i get a Traceback for import csv and cannot import name reader...

Comment: @Jose This could happen if you have another file called csv.py somewhere that python is importing instead of the standard library module.

Comment: @JoãoGFarias Thanks for your help too but i dont what was heppening with this fonction